# How to run a single jenkinsfile for specific github components

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to execute specific components that I organized in Files in the repository with only one main jenkinsfile.

For example I have this repo structure:

[image: basic_structure]

And I have three different components: Topic_A, Topic_B, Topic_C (same type of components but will be created for different teams).
I want to be able to modify only Topic_A and C and after I push the branch I want my jenkinsfile to able to execute just those changes instead also redeploying Topic_B which it was not modified.

My question is if this possible? Could it be done with a jenkins pipeline? or any other component? (script)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible within the same repository. What is your rationale having it all in the same repo? If you are concerned about redundancies in the Jenkinsfikes you can use [a shared pipeline library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [changeset directive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions) that allows you to check whether a file has changed in the Git repository. But it doesn't support checking directories, hence you can do something like the below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Cloning') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/xxxx/sample.git'
            }
        }
        
        stage('TOPIC_A') {
            when { expression { isChanged("Topic_A") } }
            steps {
                echo 'Doing something for Topic A'
                }
            }
            
        stage('TOPIC_B') {
            when { expression { isChanged("Topic_B") } }
            steps {
                echo 'Doing something for Topic B'
                }
            }
    }
}

def isChanged(dirName) {
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    def folderName = dirName
        for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
            def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
            for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                def entry = entries[j]
                def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
                for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                    def file = files[k]
                    if(file.path.contains(folderName)){
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return false
}
```